# How to parse the HTTPOutput of the HTTP Transformation to a target table in PowerCenter?

Tags: regex, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm using HTTP Transformation to call a REST Web Service.

**The problem I'm having is how am I going to map the HTTPOutput to a corresponding field of a SQL Server table? Can I just split the HTTPOutput via Expression? If yes, how can I split this.**

**This will be the response that I'll get (*This is a just sample response*)**

> {"Response": {"ns0:Resp": {     "xmlns:ns0": "UserIDRespone",
>   "ns0:messageStatus": {"ns0:StatusRequest": "SUCCESS"},
>   "ns0:payload":    { 
>         "ns0:lowerUserIDresp": "100001", 
>         "ns0:HigherUserIDresp": "100005"     }

**My Target table will contain this following fields:**

- lowerUserID
- HigherUserId
- Status

**The mapping should be like this:**

- StatusRequest  = Status
- lowerUserIDresp = lowerUserID
- HigherUserIDresp = Status

Can you please help me out on this.

Appreciate for the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expression to achieve the same. The regex would be

`.*StatusRequest": "(\w*).*lowerUserIDresp": "(\w*).*HigherUserIDresp": "(\w*).*`

To see how the regex is working, check http://regexr.com/3fn2o

> How to implement this regex in Informatica

Lets say the name of column, where httpOutput is saved, is `in_HTP_RESPONSE`.

So use regular expression function in Informatica, `REG_EXTRACT`. Create Expression transformation and create 3 variable ports. The expression condition would be

- v_StatusRequest = `REG_EXTRACT(in_HTP_RESPONSE,'.*StatusRequest":
  "(\w*).*lowerUserIDresp": "(\w*).*HigherUserIDresp": "(\w*).*',1)`
- v_lowerUserIDresp = `REG_EXTRACT(in_HTP_RESPONSE,'.*StatusRequest":
  "(\w*).*lowerUserIDresp": "(\w*).*HigherUserIDresp": "(\w*).*',2)`
- v_HigherUserIDresp = `REG_EXTRACT(in_HTP_RESPONSE,'.*StatusRequest":
  "(\w*).*lowerUserIDresp": "(\w*).*HigherUserIDresp": "(\w*).*',3)`

Now you can use these as either output ports, or you can cast the integer values as `integer` and insert in the target.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can write a java code for JSON Parser in Java transformation . You can parse any key-value and get it in any of your column.

Refrence ::
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html